# Loop through options of a radio button from umbraco

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I'm using a radio button list in umbraco cms:

[image]

I know how to get the value that the cms user chose, but how can I loop through (list out) all the options that the radio button list has?

Ideally I would like to have html like this which highlights the one they chose:

```
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li class="chosen">B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to do this using Razor.

Comment: Take a look at the DatatypeService, you can get prevalues for any data type through there. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/datatypeservice/

Comment: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/radiobutton-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the id of the radio button list datatype you created then use `DataTypeService` to enumerate all options from that radio button list.

```
<ul>
    @{
        var optionsDataTypeId = 1068; // your datatype id
        var selectedOption = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("favoritePet"));
        foreach (var option in Umbraco.DataTypeService.GetPreValuesCollectionByDataTypeId(optionsDataTypeId).PreValuesAsDictionary.Values)
        {
            <li class="@(option.Value == selectedOption ? "chosen" : "")">@option.Value</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```